# Generate Gaussian vectors

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $P$ be a given $n \times n$ symmetric positive definite real matrix. The objective is to generate a vector according to the distribution $\mathcal{N}(0, P^{-1}).$

One way to do this is to generate $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I_n)$ and then multiply it by $P^{-1/2}.$

I wish to know if one can do the same in an inexpensive fashion? That is, without having to compute explicitly $P^{-1/2}$ or use some expensive decomposition of $P.$

If the above is not possible, is it possible to acquire a sample which is approximately $\mathcal{N}(0, P^{-1})$ using cheap computations?

Comment: Do you consider Cholesky as expensive? How large is $n$?

Comment: Usual decompositions, in general, take $O(n^3)$ operations. Because of this reason, I consider them expensive.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply compute $P^{1/2}$ using a Cholesky factorization and then solve the linear system $P^{1/2} Y = X$ for $Y$, which can be done very efficiently using a substitution algorithm since $P^{1/2}$ is triangular. That way, you do not assemble $P^{-1}$ or $P^{-1/2}$.

EDIT: In this answer, I used the notion $B = A^{1/2}$ for a matrix such that $BB^T = A$, which might be non-standard.

Comment: Basic idea is right, but Cholesky doesn't compute $P^{1/2}$ (which is not triangular either): it computes lower triangular $L$ so that $P = L L^T$.   And then take $Y$ so $L^T Y = X$.

Comment: I used the notional $B=A^{1/2}$ for a matrix such that $BB^T = A$. I'll precise that (but it seems that the question uses the same notation).